# Meteor.users.findOne() returns undefined but it's still working

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am gettin' into touch with meteor.js and I am quite confused about some things.

I wrote a new collection :

```
sendEmailAfterNotification = function(comment) {

  var post = Posts.findOne(comment.postId);

  if (comment.userId !== post.userId) {

    Meteor.call('sendEmail',
                Meteor.users.findOne(post.userId).emails[0].address,
                'automailer@yourdomain.com',
                comment.author + ' answered on your post : ' + post.title,
                'random bodytext');

  }
};
```

my meteor console output is totally fine I'll get :

```
I20160424-16:00:54.758(2)? ====== BEGIN MAIL #0 ======
I20160424-16:00:54.766(2)? (Mail not sent; to enable sending, set the MAIL_URL environment variable.)
I20160424-16:00:54.767(2)? MIME-Version: 1.0
I20160424-16:00:54.767(2)? From: automailer@yourdomain.com
I20160424-16:00:54.767(2)? To: test@testdomain.com
I20160424-16:00:54.767(2)? Subject: testuser answered on your post : foobar
I20160424-16:00:54.767(2)? Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
I20160424-16:00:54.767(2)? Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
I20160424-16:00:54.767(2)? 
I20160424-16:00:54.768(2)? random body text
I20160424-16:00:54.768(2)? ====== END MAIL #0 ======
```

but in my browser I still get an errorcode :

> Exception while simulating the effect of invoking 'commentInsert' TypeError: Cannot read property 'emails' of undefined(…) TypeError: Cannot read property 'emails' of undefined

the function gets called here :
**comments.js**

```
Comments = new Mongo.Collection('comments');

Meteor.methods({
  commentInsert: function(commentAttributes) {
  check(this.userId, String);
  check(commentAttributes, {
  postId: String,
  body: String
});

var user = Meteor.user();
var post = Posts.findOne(commentAttributes.postId);

if (!post)
  throw new Meteor.Error('invalid-comment', 'You must comment on a post');

comment = _.extend(commentAttributes, {
  userId: user._id,
  author: user.username,
  submitted: new Date()
});

// update the post with the number of comments
Posts.update(comment.postId, {$inc: {commentsCount: 1}});

// create the comment, save the id
comment._id = Comments.insert(comment);

// now create a notification, informing the user that there's been a comment
createCommentNotification(comment);

// send an email to the post owner - if it's not the owner
sendEmailAfterNotification(comment);

return comment._id;
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Meteor.users.findOne(post.userId)` doesn't work on the client, since the client only has the current user's data in `Meteor.users` collection. Make sure your server-side `sendEmail` is the one that queries `Meteor.users`, and not the client.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor.users works on the client, just ensure you have published and subscribed to `Meteor.users.find({},{})` manually.

Comment: It returns undefined, because you are trying to fetch data from a source that you haven't subscribed to

Comment: And publishing all of the users' data is not really advised (both for security and for performance purposes).

Comment: he could just publish the required user or publish based on the necessary criteria